# Notepad++ conditional replace

Tags: notepad++

Task: Replace CRLF with space before lines where *first alphabetic sequence* does not consist of all capitals.

Text I have:

```
FOO Bar 123 sometext BAR sometext
Foobar, sometext 123
FOOBAR^&%# sometext sometext 1234 5678
Bar 123 456 FOO 789
barfoobar sometext
BAR; sometext (*&%#) FOOBAR 123
```

Expected result:

```
FOO Bar 123 sometext BAR sometext Foobar, sometext 123
FOOBAR^&%# sometext sometext 1234 5678 Bar 123 456 FOO 789 barfoobar sometext
BAR; sometext (*&%#) FOOBAR 123
```

Well, forgot to mention (if it matters at all), the source text in Russian (Cyrillic, Windows-1251), sample below.

```
AБИДЖАН (Abidjan) , город и главный порт государства Кот-д'Ивуар,
Aдминистративный центр деп. Абиджан. Ок. 2 млн. жителей 
Aдм. ц. французской колонии Берег Слоновой Кости (БСК). В 1960-83 столица Государства БСК.
```

Thanks very much for any help.

Cheers,

Michael

Comment: Well, I tried: https://regex101.com/r/H9Ncxa/5
Someone else might be able to fix my expression, but it's pretty close to the desired output.

Comment: I'll try to fix it later, but too checked out for the moment. Are you limited to using only notepad++, though? This might be easier to do if you wrote a small script to operate on matched text.

Comment: Thanks @aaaa , I need result by whatever mean, not necessarily with Notepad++. I will futher process the text with MS SQL, but need to clean it up first before importing.

Comment: That's helpful to know. I'll try to give it a go when I have some free time again -- unless someone beats me to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After series of experiments I could develop 3-step solution.

1. Search `(\n[А-Я] ?[A-Я]+)` , replace with `\n#$1` (https://regex101.com/r/nVHqUt/1) .
2. Search `\r\n` , replace with space.
3. Search `#\n` , replace with `\r\n`.

Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 1):

### Use regex replace, with unicode sequences

Open find and replace

Enable "Match case"

Set search mode to "Regular expression"

Find what: `\r\n([\u0600-\u06FF]{0,1}[\u0061-\u007A]{1,})`

Replace with:  `$1`  (the space is important)

Comment: My previous answer was wrong, so I've changed to a single regex replace. You'll have to try it on your actual text. My answer here might still be wrong, so can you post the original cyrillic text?

Comment: Thanks @gburton! As far as I can see this replacement makes opposite to what I need ;)

Comment: I am happy to provide samples of source text and result, but have no idea where to place them - comment field is too small and limited with formatting options

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\R(?![A-ZА-Я]+\b)`
- Replace with: `A single space`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\R                  # any kind of linebreak (i.e. \r, \n, \r\n)
(?!                 # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't after:
    [A-ZА-Я]+           # Capital Latin & Cyrillic letters
    \b                  # word boundary, make sure we match a whole word
)                   # end lookahead
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: That's a pretty slick solution. I wish I had thought of the problem differently.